# Como conectar um docker container python com um sqlserver

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, django, docker

Eu quero criar um container python3 que consiga se conectar em um SQLSERVER, estou usando o Django na minha aplicação e ele não possui um driver nativo para fazer essa conexão.
Criei uma imagem para já deixar configurado o python3 com os respectivos drivers:

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10

# apt-get and system utilities
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl apt-utils apt-transport-https debconf-utils gcc build-essential g++-9

# adding custom MS repository
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# install SQL Server drivers
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev

# install SQL Server tools
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

# python libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.6 python3-pip python3-dev python3-setuptools \
    --no-install-recommends

# install necessary locales
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# install SQL Server Python SQL Server connector module - pyodbc
RUN pip3 install pyodbc
```

E o dockerfile, que usa a imagem construida acima, da aplicação é:

```
FROM matheusrbarbosa/python3-mssql

RUN mkdir app

COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN pip3 install -r app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /app/webservice/
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

E as configurações no `settings.py` é

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': 1433,
    }
}
```

Sendo que os valores da conexão são passados por variaveis de ambiente...

O problema é que eu já tentei de tudo para fazer o driver dessa conexão funcionar, e não obtive sucesso. O erro de driver é:

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: Qual a string de conexão usada no `pyodbc.connect()` ?

Comment: A mensagem de erro diz que nao encontra o 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', voce não o instalou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuçando os arquivos do container eu achei o .ini que supostamente indica a versão do ODBC instalado, lá estava `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, ou seja, a versão do driver do container era 17, equanto a default da lib era 13. Então para apontar e versão correta do driver adicioneu as seguintees opções no `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': DB_NAME,
    'USER': DB_USERNAME,
    'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
    'HOST': DB_HOST,
    'PORT': 1433,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    },
  }
}
```

Dessa forma, o python vai procurar pelo driver da versão 17.